# Mysql table affected by insert trigger has multiple sources

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a table in my schema which looks like this:

```
X(rID(PK), cellID, Pos, type, serial, version, vendorType,invType,opState, freq, rackNo, bandID, statusID).
```

This table X is supposed to give aggregate information about the devices we have.

I have 3 triggers on this table -- insert, update, delete so that when something like a status or position changes of the device, the changes are reflected into a different table which tracks the history of this table.

The issue: field 1 is the primary key, so it has to be manually inputted, fields 2,10,12,13 are FKs and come from other tables PKs, and fields 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11 are all info coming directly from a reporting server (which i have stored in another table, but they are not FKs).

I want to insert into X in one try. Not have three separate inserts, because that would mean three separate rows into this history-tracking table for every row in X... which is a problem.

I am using phpmyadmin and mysql. Is there something I can do here to combine all of this in one insert (the update/delete triggers arent a huge issue right now)?

Comment: Sure, have all the data available at one time. So do that.

Comment: But it needs to be done as automated as possible...

Comment: Then think when you were planning on filling in the other holes. Only you know the timeline for that. Perhaps delay it until available. Or, do it in stages. Or, tweak your schema with another column as a flag that can suppress other routines (triggers, you name it) to suggest that the row is not for real yet. Treat the row like a workflow (like a mortgage application). Just because the application is not filled out yet perfectly doesn't mean it can't be logged and given a status. Note, that concept doesn't work so great for financial transactions and SOX Compliance. Just saying.