# Filling out table in relationship one to many - many to one

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 3 tables 'Company', 'Company_Officer', 'Officer'. Companies are unique and Officers are unique but officer could work for multiple companies with different roles therefore Company (1) - (many) Company_Officer (many) - (1) Officer.

Company:

```
Company_ID
Company_Name
```

Company_Officer:

```
Company_Officer_ID
Company_ID
Officer_ID
Officer_Role
```

Officer:

```
Officer_ID
Officer_Name
```

Here is how I fill out Company & Officer tables

```
foreach($YQL->getConstituents() as $key=>$companyName){
    $company[$key] = new Company($companyName);
    if($company[$key]->getCompanyFound()==true){
        array_push($Company_Details,array($company[$key]->getCompanyName(),$company[$key]->getCompanyNumber(),"FTSE 100"));
        foreach ($company[$key]->getCompanyOfficers() as $officer){
            array_push($Officer_Details,array($officer[0],$officer[2]));
        }
    }
}
$Company_Details = array_unique($Company_Details, SORT_REGULAR);
$Officer_Details = array_unique($Officer_Details, SORT_REGULAR);

$DAO->insertMultiOnDuplicateData("Company_Details", array("Company_Name","Company_Number", "Company_Index"), $Company_Details, array("Company_Index"));
$DAO->insertMultiData("Officer_Details", array("Officer_Name","Officer_Resigned"), $Officer_Details);
```

If a record of Officer/Company already exists only additional fields would be updated the whole row will not be inserted again since Officers/Companies are unique.

But I have no idea how to fill out Company_Officer since it requires Company_ID & Officer_ID which I don't have while executing this code is there a simple solution to this problem? Should I just insert Officers/Companies then get them all back from database to receive IDs of companies and officers and compare to arrays that I have used to update the database?

Comment: So change the way you are doing it so the intersect table has all it needs when the insert comes along. It is just like this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37871254) where the guy says geez how do I have all my data.

Comment: @Drew I was just thinking about making Company_ID and Officer_ID unique combination, because there could only be one specified Officer in one company

Comment: I would definitely do that. `unique key (compId,ofcId);`   or `unique key (compId,ofcId,roleId);`

Comment: @Drew since I'm updating the database I am not able to tell which company is assigned to which ID without accessing DB. I believe unfortunately that I will have to download IDs companies names (after updating the db) as well as officer IDs and names then compare those arrays to arrays that I have just used to update my database and if values match I will know what ID number for officer and company to put in company_officer table.

Comment: People have their own comfort levels and use what they know. I would leverage mysql to solve this for me with work tables and I know it would be the fastest. Assuming the mysql programming language is not lacking it granularity of what is necessary and only offered by a high-level programming language like PHP. That is because I do large data ingest and I know mysql. Others use PHP loops. They use what they know. Just like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37897221) question and what he would do, and what I would do.